# Generic method arguments

Tags: c#, .net, methods

I have a method that accepts `string[]` arguments

```
public static void MyMethod(string[] s1, string[] s2, string[] s3, string[] s4)
{

}
```

Sometimes I have the situation that instead of `string[]` I would like to use a normal `string`

Is it possible to set the method's generic arguments to accept either an array or plain text?

What I need (examples):

```
MyMethod(["a", "b"], ["s", "m"], ["i", "k"], ["a", "e"])
MyMethod(["a", "p"], "u", ["v", "p"], "e")
MyMethod("a", "b", "b", "d")
```

and other combinations

Comment: Create one more method with the desired signature. This called overloading methods

Comment: Just use overloads

Comment: No, it's not possible. However, you can overload the method to do so.

Comment: I would have to create overloads for each combination. I thought about it but it is not a good way

Comment: Try something like: `public static void MyMethod(params string[] s)` and an overload `public static void MyMethod(params string s)`

Comment: This is not what generics _do_. A `string` is not a `string[]`, and a generic parameter wouldn't help you _even if it were_. As others have stated, this is what function overloading is for. Alternatively, your callers can simply _put a single string in an array_ to call this method, as is.

Comment: Might be worth a bit of an explanation of why you want to pass four arrays of strings. It seems unusual.

Comment: Can you change your method to accept ienumerables instead of arrays? That way, at least, the caller can just use `Enumerable.Repeat(singleString,1)` if they don't have an array at hand.

Comment: You could create an own class for the input parameter - like a `StringInput` class, which can hide the details of containing one string or an array. It can have multiple constructors with diferent types, so it can be created from an array and from a single string, and it can have methods like `IsSingleString()` or `GetStringsAsArray()` that helps you implement the logic in a general way.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown the `params` should be a single dimensional array. I am afraid your second overload won't even compiles!

Comment: @Annosz yes, was going to suggest that too, plus implicit conversion operators from string and string[] to that type, and then make the function accept that type with params.

Comment: `MyMethod(["a", "b"], ["s", "m"], ["i", "k"], ["a", "e"])` is not valid C# syntax. You cannot ad-hoc create arrays by just enclosing the items in square brackets.

Comment: @DevNet So what about answers? Would you like to accept one of them if your main problem has been resolved already?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`params`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) keyword:

```
public static void MyMethod(params string[] s)
{

}
```

With this way you can either pass a simple string as a parameter to your method like this:

```
MyMethod("str");
```

Or multiple values as array:

```
MyMethod("str1","str2","str3");
```

Based on your desired result in your updated question, you might find the following implementation also useful:

```
public static void MyMethod(params string[][] s)
{

}
```

This will works for all of the samples which you've mentioned in the *What I need* section of your question.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting. What you need is as per others said using `params` with an indirection / custom type supporting implicit conversion from both `string` and `string[]`.

For example:

```
public static void MyMethod(params StringArray[] s)
{   
}

class StringArray
{
    public string[] Value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator StringArray(string str)
    {
        return new StringArray
        {
            Value = new[] { str }
        };
    }

    public static implicit operator StringArray(string[] str)
    {
        return new StringArray
        {
            Value = str
        };
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
MyMethod(new[] { "a", "b" }, new[] { "s", "m" }, new[] { "i", "k" }, new[] { "a", "e" });
MyMethod(new[] { "a", "p" }, "u", new[] { "v", "p" }, "e");
MyMethod("a", "b", "b", "d");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `params` with [jagged array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) for that

```cs
public static void MyMethod(params string[][] s1)
{
}
```

and update a method invocation a little bit

```cs
MyMethod(new[] { "a", "b" }, new[] { "s", "m" });
MyMethod(new[] { "a", "p" }, new[] { "u" }, new[] { "v", "p" }, new[] { "e" });
MyMethod(new[] { "a", "b", "b", "d" });
```

Please, keep in mind that in last line you are passing just a one-dimension array and you should properly manage it inside a method

However, it doesn't look readable enough, IMO. It's better to have a few overloads with different signatures

```cs
public static void MyMethod(params string[][] s1)
{
}
public static void MyMethod(params string[] s1)
{
}
```

Then you can have the last method call as `MyMethod("a", "b", "b", "d");`, without array declaration.

Unfortunately, you can't avoid using an array declaration with `new` operator, [target-typed `new` expression](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/100) will come in the next version of C#

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with wrapper type and implicit operator. Optionally you can add property `IsCollection` to check how the wrapper was initialized.

```
class Program
{
    static void MyMethod(StringCollection s1, StringCollection s2, StringCollection s3, StringCollection s4)
    {

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyMethod("a", "b", "c", "d");
        MyMethod(new[] { "a1", "a2" }, "b", "c", "d");
    }
}

class StringCollection
{
    public readonly bool IsCollection;
    public string[] Values;

    public StringCollection(string value)
    {
        Values = new[] { value };
        IsCollection = false;
    }

    public StringCollection(string[] values)
    {
        Values = values;
        IsCollection = true;
    }

    public static implicit operator StringCollection(string value)
    {
        return new StringCollection(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator StringCollection(string[] values)
    {
        return new StringCollection(values);
    }
}
```